# T-SQL ORDER BY number and letters mixed in string

Tags: sql, string, sql-order-by

I have a range of **unique** strings which contain numbers and sometimes numbers and a letter, a sample of which reads:

- 1X
- 2X
- 2Y
- 12X
- 20
- 21

The number/s always precede the letter. What is the ORDER BY (T-SQL) clause solution to produce a list which would give me the order as demonstrated above?

I tried using

LEN(*fieldName*), *fieldname* - which would work but for the 20 and 21. I have tried expressing the strings as an integer but the CAST fails in the conversion process.

Comment: So you want a list sorted by the number, and then by letter?

Comment: Are the alpha characters always at the end of the value as in your example, or could they be anywhere within the value?

Comment: Correct Elias, and "The number/s always precede the letter".

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(column)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,column`

Comment: The above solution focuses only on the first number i.e. If the list is 21, 12X, 1X, the order will be altered to 12X, 1X, 21. A different problem then presents itself.

Comment: Are you talking about @Mihai's comment or my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm stealing my details from [Here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=54612).

```
declare @t table(s varchar(25))
insert @t
select '122345684XT' union
select '23339034300-XT' union
select '423432424523242332X' union
 select '422222222111111111232' union
select '423842389034209XYZ' union
select 'ABC'

select 
    left(s,patindex('%[^0-9]%',S+' ')-1 ) nbr 
   ,right(s,len(s)-patindex('%[^0-9]%',S+' ')+1) alpha
from @t
```

which results in

```
122345684               XT
23339034300             -XT
422222222111111111232   
423432424523242332      X
423842389034209         XYZ
ABC
```

To use it in your context.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
ORDER BY left(s,patindex('%[^0-9]%',S+' ')-1 ), 
         right(s,len(s)-patindex('%[^0-9]%',S+' ')+1)
```

Shown by

```
declare @t table(s varchar(25))
insert @t
select '12X' union
select '1X' union
select '2X' union
select '2Y' union
select '20' union
select '21'

SELECT * 
FROM @t
ORDER BY CAST(left(s,patindex('%[^0-9]%',S+' ')-1 ) AS INT), 
         right(s,len(s)-patindex('%[^0-9]%',S+' ')+1)
```

Results In

```
1X
2X
2Y
12X
20
21
```

Comment: Having implemented the code and tested a few dozen combinations this appears to be functioning exactly as required. Thank you.