# SQL Query - Order by String (which contains number and chars)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with a `sql` query which I can't get it work. I need to order these values by number then by letter.

Any suggestion how to do it?

I am working on `Sql Server 2014`, but I think it's irrelevant.

```
Cod_Turma   Turma
1           11-A
2           11-F
3           10-F
4           11-G
5           11-I
6           10-E
7           12-L
8           10-J
9           7-B
10          9-B
11          7-E
12          7-D
13          12-H
```

Output should be:

```
Cod_Turma   Turma
9           7-B
12          7-D
11          7-E
10          9-B
...
```

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25386039/2932678

Comment: Is it always in `<number>-<single letter>` format?

Comment: yes, these are school classes data, at least in my country we got this format, 12th degree then comes the letter for each class. I can normalize it, but it's" way to much work" for the purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(Turma, CHARINDEX('-', Turma) - 1) AS INT), --left part
         SUBSTRING(Turma, CHARINDEX('-', turma), LEN(turma))  --right part
```

Comment: This is probably a little easier to understand than mine, I always forget that `SUBSTRING` in SQL allows you to overrun the length of the string for the length parameter.

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @t table (cod_turma int, turma varchar(10));

INSERT @t values
 (1,'11-A')
,(2,'11-F')
,(3,'10-F')
,(4,'11-G')
,(5,'11-I')
,(6,'10-E')
,(7,'12-L')
,(8,'10-J')
,(9,'7-B' )
,(10,'9-B')
,(11,'7-E')
,(12,'7-D')
,(13,'12-H')

SELECT * FROM @t
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(Turma, CHARINDEX('-', Turma)-1) AS INT), SUBSTRING(turma, CHARINDEX('-', Turma), 1000)
```

Explanation: Parse Turma out into two separate values (the int and the character); cast the int part to int (so that you don't get an ordering of `1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 31`) and order by that, then order by the letter part.

I've edited this to reflect improvements suggested by @Giorgi Nakeuri's post as well as a comment by @TimSchemlter.
(Note: my initial post did not work, I tried to fire from the hip and used some incorrect syntax.)

Comment: Check Giorgi's answer.  I was trying to avoid overrunning a length parameter in substring, thinking more in a C# mindset.

Comment: I've edited my answer so that future readers won't take a worse solution, but I hope it's clear that credit should go to @Giorgi, not me.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and **dirty** (just for numbers **< 100**):

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl
ORDER BY REPLICATE(' ', CASE SUBSTRING([turma], 2, 1) WHEN '-' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
         + turma
;
```

but works: [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/531e7/7)

Answer (score 0):

I think Dan's and Giorgi answers are both good, but for variety's sake, here's an alternative using a little PARSENAME() trick.

```
SELECT  Cod_Turma,
        Turma
FROM @yourTable
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REPLACE(Turma,'-','.')) CA(par)
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(par,2) AS INT),PARSENAME(par,1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Order by ascending order will sort by numbers first and then alphabets.
select Cod_Turma, Turma from tableXX  order by Turma asc

Comment: that would be the lexicographical order. the OP wants to sort by the number first and then by the text part.